# Copying a character from one string argument to another in C

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition, isomorphism

The following program crashes without an error message after trying to replace the first character in s with t. The purpose of the program is to test if the two strings s and t are isomorphic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isIsomorphic(char *s, char *t);

int main()
{
    isIsomorphic("egg", "add");
}

bool isIsomorphic(char *s, char *t)
{
    //create two other char pointers for the characters one position before s and t.
    char *preS = s; 
    char *preT = t; 

    //replace first character in s with t.
    *s = *t //CRASHES HERE

    //increment both pointers to their second character.
    s ++;
    t ++;

    //run through t
    while(t != NULL)
    {
        //if the characters in both strings are either a. both equal to their previous or b. both different to their previous:
        if(((strcmp(t, preT) == 0) && (strcmp(s, preS) == 0)) || (((strcmp(t, preT) != 0) && (strcmp(s, preS) != 0))))
        {
            //copy t into s and shift both pointers along.
            *s = *t;
            s ++;
            t ++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not isomorphic\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    printf("isomorphic\n");
    return true;
}
```

Why is this the case? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Modifying string literals is prohivited. Trying to do so invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your function will work for stings that have dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying string literals is prohibited. Trying to do so invokes *undefined behavior*.

In this case the pointers are incremented after the assignments and the strings are not referenced after the call of `isIsomorphic` function, so you should remove the meaningless and harmful assignments (`*s = *t;`).

If you want to refer the modified string later, you should store the string to modify in a modifiable array like this:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "egg";
    isIsomorphic(str, "add");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using string literals

```
isIsomorphic("egg", "add");
```

that you are changing within the function `isIsomorphic`

```
*s = *t //CRASHES HERE
```

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

But in any case the function is incorrect.

Firstly the function shall not change passed to it strings. That is it shall be declared like

```
bool isIsomorphic( const char *s, const char *t);
```

Also these calls of the function `strcmp` in the if statement

```
if(((strcmp(t, preT) == 0) && (strcmp(s, preS) == 0)) || (((strcmp(t, preT) != 0) && (strcmp(s, preS) != 0))))
```

do not make a sense at least because strings pointed to by `t` and `preT` have different lengths. So this expression `strcmp(t, preT) == 0` will always evaluate to logical false.

I can suggest the following function definition shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isIsomorphic( const char *s, const char *t )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    bool isomorphic = n == strlen( t );
    
    while ( isomorphic && n-- )
    {
        const char *p1 = strchr( s + n + 1, s[n] );
        const char *p2 = strchr( t + n + 1, t[n] );
        
        isomorphic = ( !p1 && !p2 ) || ( p1 && p2 && p1 - s == p2 - t );  
    }
    
    return isomorphic;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "egg";
    const char *t = "add";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is isomorphic with \"%s\" is %s\n", 
            s, t, isIsomorphic( s, t ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "foo";
    t = "bar";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is isomorphic with \"%s\" is %s\n", 
            s, t, isIsomorphic( s, t ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "paper";
    t = "title";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is isomorphic with \"%s\" is %s\n", 
            s, t, isIsomorphic( s, t ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "0123456789";
    t = "9876543210";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is isomorphic with \"%s\" is %s\n", 
            s, t, isIsomorphic( s, t ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"egg" is isomorphic with "add" is true
"foo" is isomorphic with "bar" is false
"paper" is isomorphic with "title" is true
"0123456789" is isomorphic with "9876543210" is true
```